# Download podcast in Python

Tags: python, podcast

I want to search and download podcasts at https://podcasts.apple.com.
First I use the following code to search.

```
import podsearch
podcasts = podsearch.search("python", country="us", limit=10)
link=podcasts[0].url
```

Now I want to get the mp3 file link for download, and the title of the episodes as well as the description of the episodes.
If I want to use the requests library to extract links, I can only get the last 6 episodes. How do I get links to all episodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `podsearch` library does not seem to support this capability. Also, when using `requests` to do a HTTP GET on the podcast page, you would indeed just receive the 6 latests episodes, similar to what you would get when accessing the URL manually (e.g. https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/id979020229).

You would have to choose another library or use Selenium to dynamically click on the "Show 10 More Episodes" link from the iTunes page.

Comment: Is there a library for this?

Comment: Not that I know of. But, if your podcast have an RSS feed, then it would be way easier to just query the RSS feed directly and get the download link from there. For RSS feed, you can use something like https://pypi.org/project/feedparser/

Comment: @JChris Once you have that link how would you download it? Just Wget?